# What is the opposite of embed?

Tags: terminology, encoding

We often embed items from one space into another space, e.g. embedding plaintext items from $\{0, 1\}^m$ into some ring $R_q/\langle x^N + 1 \rangle$ for RingLWE.

What is the inverse of this action called?

(Feel free to move this question to Math.SE or other related. Though I am specifically interested in the opposite of embed in the context of math and crypto, rather than the general English language.)

Comment: There is no universally agreed dedicated term in the cryptographic community, as far as I'm aware of. One can say project, as kodlu suggests; I would personally use "decode", or perhaps something like "the party embeds the ring element back into $\{0,1\}^m$".

Comment: Surly there must be a generic mathematical function for this. I would suggest that the definition of _"embed"_ is the real question here. The inverse is then just the reciprocal of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed usually implies the target algebraic structure is of larger cardinality (assuming finite). So, I would say project.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of the verb *embed* is ***dislodge*** or ***uproot***.

When we say that something is ***embedded***, we mean that it is somehow ***attached*** by virtue of being ***in*** something else, at least partially.

In other words, it is going to take some kind of action to remove something that is embedded.

[The etymology of ***embed***](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=embed) illustrates the point:

*Embed*

> embed (v.) 1778, "to lay in a bed (of surrounding matter)," from em-
> (1) + bed (n.). **Originally a geological term, in reference to fossils
> in rock**; figurative sense is by 1835; meaning "place (a journalist)
> within a military unit at war" is from 2003 and the Iraq war. Related:
> Embedded; embedding.

I have discussed the general definition of *embed* so you can accurately apply that to math and crypto since it seems that there is no distinct mathematical/cryptographic meaning for this verb.